# Cannot compile Vcg library in VS 2010

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, header-files, mesh, vcg

I'm trying to write simple program using `VCG` library
But I can't even pass compilation in VS 2010.
i copied  example file from official page but it fails on this line

```
class MyMesh    : public vcg::tri::TriMesh< std::vector<MyVertex>, std::vector<MyFace> , std::vector<MyEdge>  > {};
```

Compiler says`Error 10  error C2248: 'vcg::tri::TriMesh<Container0,Container1,Container2>::TriMesh' : cannot access private member declared in class 'vcg::tri::TriMesh<Container0,Container1,Container2>'...meshes\meshprocessing.h    24  1   Meshes`

here's my full meshprocessing.h code

```
#include<vcg/complex/complex.h>
#include<vcg/complex/append.h>
#include<vcg/complex/algorithms/clean.h>
#include<vcg/complex/algorithms/hole.h>
#include<vcg/container/container_allocation_table.h>
#include<wrap\io_trimesh\import.h>
#include<wrap\io_trimesh\export.h>
#include <vector>
#include<iostream>

#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/PolygonMesh.h>

class MyVertex; class MyEdge; class MyFace;
struct MyUsedTypes : public vcg::UsedTypes<vcg::Use<MyVertex>   ::AsVertexType,
                                           vcg::Use<MyEdge>     ::AsEdgeType,
                                           vcg::Use<MyFace>     ::AsFaceType>{};
class MyVertex  : public vcg::Vertex< MyUsedTypes, vcg::vertex::Coord3f, vcg::vertex::Normal3f, vcg::vertex::BitFlags  >{};
class MyFace    : public vcg::Face<   MyUsedTypes, vcg::face::FFAdj,  vcg::face::VertexRef, vcg::face::BitFlags > {};
class MyEdge    : public vcg::Edge<   MyUsedTypes> {};
class MyMesh    : public vcg::tri::TriMesh< std::vector<MyVertex>, std::vector<MyFace> , std::vector<MyEdge>  > {};


class MeshProcessing
{
private:
    MyMesh mesh;
    pcl::PolygonMesh polygonMesh;
public:
    MeshProcessing(pcl::PolygonMesh mesh);
    MyMesh pclMeshtoVcgMesh();
    MyMesh reorientNormals(MyMesh mesh);
};
```

I don't know what to do with it, any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

```
#include "MeshProcessing.h"

MeshProcessing::MeshProcessing(pcl::PolygonMesh mesh){
    MeshProcessing::polygonMesh=mesh;
}
MyMesh MeshProcessing::pclMeshtoVcgMesh(){
    MyMesh vcgMesh;
    int verticeCount;
    int triangleCount;

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> tmp_cloud; 
    pcl:fromROSMsg(polygonMesh.cloud,tmp_cloud);
    vcgMesh.Clear();
    verticeCount=tmp_cloud.width*tmp_cloud.height;
    vcg::tri::Allocator<MyMesh>::AddVertices(vcgMesh,verticeCount);
    for(int i=0;i<verticeCount;i++){
        vcgMesh.vert[i].P()=vcg::Point3f(tmp_cloud.points[i].x,tmp_cloud.points[i].y,tmp_cloud.points[i].z);

    }
    triangleCount=polygonMesh.polygons.size();
    vcg::tri::Allocator<MyMesh>::AddFaces(vcgMesh, triangleCount);
    for(int i=0;i<triangleCount;i++){
        vcgMesh.face[i].V(0)=&vcgMesh.vert[polygonMesh.polygons[i].vertices[0]];
        vcgMesh.face[i].V(1)=&vcgMesh.vert[polygonMesh.polygons[i].vertices[1]];
        vcgMesh.face[i].V(2)=&vcgMesh.vert[polygonMesh.polygons[i].vertices[2]];
    }
    printf("Input mesh  vn:%i fn:%i\n",vcgMesh.VN(),vcgMesh.FN());


    return vcgMesh;


}

MyMesh reorientNormals(MyMesh mesh){
    bool orientable=true;
    bool oriented=false;
    vcg::tri::Clean<MyMesh>::RemoveNonManifoldFace(mesh);
    vcg::tri::Clean<MyMesh>::OrientCoherentlyMesh(mesh,oriented,orientable);
    vcg::tri::UpdateNormal<MyMesh>::PerVertexNormalizedPerFace(mesh);
    vcg::tri::UpdateNormal<MyMesh>::PerVertexFromCurrentFaceNormal(mesh);

    return mesh;

}
```

Comment: `#include<wrap\io_trimesh\import.h>
#include<wrap\io_trimesh\export.h>` should be `#include<wrap/io_trimesh/import.h>
#include<wrap/io_trimesh/export.h>`

Comment: It didnt help. When i comment out lines using "trimesh" in cpp file. Everything is compiled fine. Ive edited post and added cpp file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private:
     // TriMesh cannot be copied. Use Append (see vcg/complex/trimesh/append.h)\
     TriMesh operator =(const TriMesh &  m){assert(0);return TriMesh();}
     TriMesh(const TriMesh & ){}
```

Copy/pasted from base.h in the VCG library.  This is a standard trick, with a really crappy error message that inspired C++11's `= delete` synax.  Since you derive from TriMesh, you in turn must declare your own since the compiler-generated ones cannot work.  Fix:

```
class MyMesh : public yadayada...
{
private:
    MyMesh operator=(const TriMesh &) /* = delete */;
    MyMesh(const TriMesh &) /* = delete */;
};
```

Comment: Ok i understand your solution now only remaining problem is how do i contruct new object in .cpp file